# Join 2 Sheets together on particular columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets Document with 2 Sheets, Inventory and Pending Transactions.
My goal is to create a new sheet with Available items.

```
Company,Item,Quantity
Walmart,ToyA,100
Walmart,ToyB,5
Amazon,ToyA,2000
Amazon,ToyB,100
Amazon,ToyC,5
----
Company,Item,Pending
Walmart,ToyA,2
Walmart,ToyB,4
Amazon,ToyA,1990
```

My idea is to Join the Items together.

```
Company,Item,Inventory,Pending,Available
Walmart,ToyA,100,2,{Computed}
Walmart,ToyB,5,2,{Computed}
Amazon,ToyA,2000,1990,{Computed}    # All of the {Computed is Inventory minus Pending}
Amazon,ToyB,100,2,{Computed}
Amazon,ToyC,5,2,{Computed}
```

My Original idea was to Show the items merged on a Primary key of Company:Item, but i have no problem creating a new sheet which handles all of this. I was trying to do things like: `=Query({Sheet1!A:D;Sheet2!A:D}, "select *")` but that appends Sheet2 to the End of Sheet1, which is not what I wanted.

I got stumped, and after looking at a bunch of different Questions I couldnt find the example I was looking at.

Comment: Would you be open to using Apps Script [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)?

Answer (score 0):

To merge the items without blank rows, use

```
={QUERY(Sheet1!A2:D, "SELECT * where not A like '' ");
QUERY(Sheet2!A2:D, "SELECT * where not A like '' ")}
```

if you want to know from which sheet the data are coming, use

```
=QUERY({
ARRAYFORMULA({IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A2:A),,"#1") ,Sheet1!A2:D});
ARRAYFORMULA({IF(ISBLANK(Sheet2!A2:A),,"#2") ,Sheet2!A2:D})
},"select * where Col1 <> '' ")
```

Comment: This isnt the same as:   `=Query({Sheet1!A:A;Sheet2!A:A}, "select *" )` is it?  Cause that will append to the end in the colums. I was working to put like sheet1 a-d into out, and then sheet2 a-d into out [e-h]